# How to add a column from one dataframe to another dataframe based on multiple colums

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

Suppose if I've two dataframes df1 and df2.

Df1:
ID First_name Second_Name   dob
Outputt

1. Sam.       Daniel.    1/28/1997
2. Dave.      Cullen.    3/18/1997
3. David.      Bell.     2/18/2000

Df2:
ID First_name Second_Name dob.  Output

1. Sam.       Daniel.   1/28/1997   1
2. Dave.      Cullen.    3/18/1997  0
3. David.      Bell.    2/18/2000 1

Result

Df1
ID First_name Second_Name   dob   Output

1. Sam.       Daniel.    1/28/1997  1
2. Dave.      Cullen.    3/18/1997 0
3. David.      Bell.     2/18/2000 1

As you can see, I want to add the output column from df2 to df1 based on ID, even if the ID is wrong in this case David who has 301 ID in df2 and 3 in df1 still I want the output as 1, since the person has the same first_name, last_name and Dob.

I've tried adding output based on just ID, using

```
Df3 = df1.join(df2.set_index('ID'), on='ID', how = 'left')
```

This worked for me,but this was only considering ID, I want to add output to the df1 based on the first_name, last_name and dob just incase if the ID is wrong.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you need `Df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['First_name','Second_Name',''dob], how = 'left')` ?

Comment: What about ID? That's my primary checker, incase if ID is wrong then I want to merge using, first_name, second_name, dob, so this way, I won't lose any data, that's the only reason, but will this work?

Comment: Sorry, then not sure if undertand, mainly because in sample data are same ID 1,2,3. So not possible test this scenario. Is possible change data sample for this?